# Newline character in print statement PHP

Tags: php

Another question for all you pros out here.  I am still trying to learn the language and don't want to pick up any bad habits along the way, and it is easier to fix a problem now rather than later when it is a habit.

This is regarding the correct way to use the \n in a string.

They way the book I am reading does it is as follows:

```
print "$student: $grade<br />\n";
```

After some reading, I have heard that it is best practice to use single quotes whenever possible, and this is how I have written the same statement:

```
print $student . ': ' . $grade . '<br />' . "\n";
```

What is the preferred method of doing this?  Is the books way or my way more correct?

It seems like the books way is easier to read when reviewing the code, so should I use double or single quotes in a situation like this?

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: My opinion, you are almost certainly worrying about nothing.

Comment: String interpolation is a valuable PHP language feature.  There's little reason to avoid using it in favor of single quotes and concatenation.  Under certain circumstances concatenation can be faster than interpolation, but the readability of the double quoted version is, IMHO, much more important almost all the time.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Scroll down to PHP_EOL.

EOL refers to 'end of line'.